# How should i model my attendance system?

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

I am trying to make a system in Java to log user attendance in a project.

- The users have individual timetables (different days and time).
- The users have different start and ending dates in the project.

Currently i have these two tables.

- USERS(user_id, firstname, lastname)
- ATTENDANCE(user_id, login_date, login_time, isPresent)

I'm struggling to see a good way of connecting ATTENDANCE data to a yet undefined third table which hold info about the users timetable.

Currently i get attendance data correctly into the ATTENDANCE table, but i have nothing to check it against actual days or time their supposed to be here.

Comment: You can add a new column on the "ATTENDANCE" table like attendance_id and create the third table using two foreign key namely: user_id and attendance_id.

Comment: the third table is the table with the project's start and end dates for each user? I think you need at least four tables: users, projects, user-project schedules, user attendances which could also include the project id (for example if a user can be scheduled at the same time for two projects but can attend only one of them)